# GData.xcodepro for google search API

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am new iPhone developer and I am trying to create an iphone application. I need Gdata for that application. I find GData.xcodeproj but I cant download it. I get this code on this link :- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FGData.xcodeproj can anybody help me..??

Comment: Radhu, It's a project hosted read only, So If you want the code, you can create a file in XCode and copy paste the code. I think there is no way...